# Удаление из базы, если значение пустое

Tags: mysql

В общем, есть таблица со столбцом visible, который по умолчанию NULL.
Сам столбец получает int значение 0 или 1.
В таблице, помимо строки со значением столбца visible = NULL, есть еще две строки, где его значение 0 и 1 соответственно.
Итак, пробую очевидный запрос:

> DELETE FROM table WHERE visible=NULL;

- результата нет. Ничего не удалилось.

> DELETE FROM table WHERE
> visible='';

- результат есть, удалилась строка, у которой значение было 0.

Вопрос: почему так происходит и как удалить строку, в которой значение Null?

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Working_with_NULL.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE visible IS NULL;
```

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: @makbeth, обращайтесь)